# Can I read command line Parameters passed to LOLCODE

Tags: lolcode

I'm using https://code.google.com/p/lolcode-dot-net/ to compile my LOLCODE.

Once I have the exe, I'd like to pass command line parameters to it. Is there some way of getting these params to the LoLcode (other than having a separate .net solution that writes it's command line parameters to a file so the Lolcode can read it.)

Here's some code

```
  HAI

  HOW DUZ I MAIN YR params
     VISIBLE params
  IF U SAY SO

  MAIN "I'd like this from command param"

  KTHXBYE
```

Edit: Updated the header, as David pointed out

Comment: You just pass your command line arguments on the command line that you use to start your exe file, just as you do for any other executable

Comment: But how do I pick them up in the Lolcode? Is there a reserved name for a Main method?

Comment: That's a completely different question. Do you want to know how to pass them, as you asked, or how to read them, as you didn't ask?

Comment: I'd like to know how to read them as I didn't ask, I've updated the question

Comment: Codes in LOLCODE always makes LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used lolcode-dot-net, but from your code it seems you're trying to simply pass a parameter to a function.

Per the [LOLCODE 1.2 language specs](http://lolcode.org/1.2_spec.html), this is the syntax for calling a function:

> ```
> I IZ <function name> [YR <expression1> [AN YR <expression2> [AN YR <expression3> ...]]] MKAY
> ```

This works on [compileonline.com](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lolcode_online.php):

```
HAI 1.2

  HOW IZ I MAIN YR params
     VISIBLE params
  IF U SAY SO

  I IZ MAIN YR "I'd like this from command param" MKAY

KTHXBYE
```

Output:

> ```
> I'd like this from command param
> ```